# printf %d is adding instead of replacing padded zeros

Tags: bash, ubuntu, printf, padding, zero

Long story short: printf is adding zeros to a number instead of having the number replace them.

More details:

I'm currently attempting to use Bash on my Ubuntu OS to execute a series of broken up files
containing queries for my database.

The files were broken up to look like the following:

```
x0000000000
x0000000001
x0000000002
etc.
```

I was making a small script that will run these files by using the padding zeros function of Bash's printf.

My script looks like every one I've Google'd and seen, but the results are different.

Here's my script: (Not the one for the queries, but the one to get the file name)

```
for i in {0..10};
do
printf "x%010d"$i;
done
```

Which should come out to something likes this:

```
x0000000000
x0000000001
x0000000002
x0000000003
x0000000004
x0000000005
x0000000006
x0000000007
x0000000008
x0000000009
x0000000010
```

But is instead coming out like this:

```
x00000000000
x00000000001
x00000000002
x00000000003
x00000000004
x00000000005
x00000000006
x00000000007
x00000000008
x00000000009
x000000000010
```

It's purely adding zeros to the number instead of the number replacing them.

Can someone please tell me if I unintentionally turned on some setting, did something wrong, or have a bug?

Comment: add just an space: printf "x%010d" $i;

Comment: Thank you too, I saw the other post one first.

Answer (score 2):

You need a space, otherwise concatenation occurs:

```
printf "x%010d" $i;
               ^
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you so much, this has been irking me for hours.